# Validating attribute uniqueness with XSD across XML document

Tags: php, xml, xpath, xsd, libxml2

I'm trying to validate the uniquess of an attribute across all elements that exist in an XML document.

Example XML:

```
<exampleXml>
  <a id="1"/>
  <a id="2">
    <b id="1"/>
  </a>
</exampleXml>
```

My XSD schema:

```
<xs:schema elementFormDefault="qualified">
  <xs:element name="exampleXml">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" name="a">
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:complexContent>
              <xs:extension base="baseRuleType">
                <xs:sequence>
                  <xs:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="b">
                    <xs:complexType>
                      <xs:complexContent>
                        <xs:extension base="baseRuleType"/>
                      </xs:complexContent>
                    </xs:complexType>
                  </xs:element>
                </xs:sequence>
              </xs:extension>
            </xs:complexContent>
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
    <xs:unique name="duplicateIdsForbidden">
      <xs:selector xpath="//"/>
      <xs:field xpath="@id"/>
    </xs:unique>
  </xs:element>
  <xs:complexType name="baseRuleType">
    <xs:attribute name="id" use="optional"/>
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:schema>
```

The xpath is the issue here. I want to match every element under root but the selector xpath above returns:

```
Element '{http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}selector', attribute 'xpath': 
The XPath expression '//' could not be compiled
```

I can change the xpath to "*" but that will only validate the id attribute on the elements that are direct decendants of the root.

I am validating this with lib_xml in PHP using `DOMDocument::schemaValidate()`. Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: why dont you just set the attribute type to ID or use xml:id for the ID attribute? That would enforce uniqueness automatically. The IDs cannot be numeric then though, but NCNames.

Comment: 'I can change the xpath to `*` but that will only validate the id attribute on the elements that are direct decendants of the root.' I think you mean '... that are direct *children* of the top-level element', right?

Answer (score 8):

Use `<xs:selector xpath=".//*"/>`.

Comment: Yes. To elaborate on this, `//` is equivalent to `/descendant-or-self::node()/`. Since it ends with a slash, it is not a complete XPath expression. (The exception is `/` itself.)

Comment: @Gordon @LarsH thanks guys, learnt a couple of things there that I didn't know.